# How to upload a image in JavaScript and use it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I want wanted to make this change the background of the div.

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="file">
        <div id="myBackground"></div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you mean an actual upload, like upload the input file to a server, save it, and then have the javascript set the background to that saved image. Or just straight use the input file as the div background?

Comment: read  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL

Comment: I don't think the author researched on his problem before posting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thing you mean read file from input then apply as a background of a div, use [FileReader.readAsDataURL()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL)

```js
function previewFile() {
  var preview = document.querySelector('#myBackground'),
      file    = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0],
      reader  = new FileReader();

  reader.addEventListener("load", function () {
    preview.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + reader.result + ')';
  }, false);

  if (file) {
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  }
}
```

```css
#myBackground{
  width: 150px;
  height:150px;
  background-size: cover
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="file" onchange="previewFile()"/>
        <div id="myBackground"></div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function readURL(input) {

    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#myBackground img').attr('src', e.target.result);
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}

$("#imgUpload").change(function(){
    readURL(this);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<input type="file" id="imgUpload">
  <div id="myBackground">
  <img src="#" alt="your image" />
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    function input_image_changefunction(){
                      var e;
                      var oFReader = new FileReader();
                      oFReader.readAsDataURL(document.getElementById("full_image").files[0]);

           oFReader.onloadend = function() {


        // Do what you want to to with the image here
          }
               oFReader.onload = function (oFREvent) {

         //some other action eg  load the image to the background
        document.getElementById("myBackground").src = oFREvent.target.result;
    };


}
```

then add the id and an onchange action to the file input eg

```
   <input type="file"  id="full_image" onchange="input_image_changefunction()" name="full_image" class="ssb" required="required" accept='image/*'>
```